# Is it possible to invert audio using the HTML5 audio API?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I'm playing around a little with the HTML5 Audio API and wondering if it's possible to invert waveforms?
That is, completely flip a waveform, in effect cancelling it out.

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done without JS. There is a [gain attribute here](http://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/) in 4.7.1, and setting it to -1 will reverse the phase, effectively cancelling out the audio. What are you trying to accomplish?